# Let $F\supset F_p$ be a finite field extension. Prove that $F$ is a splitting extension.

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I know that $F$ is itself a finite field and has characteristic p. Also the multiplicative group, $F^{\times}$, is cyclic.

Can someone help me take it from here?

Comment: Have you classified finite fields?

Comment: Do you see a polynomial $\in F_p[x]$ such that every $a\in F^\times$ is a root

Comment: No. Can you explain.

Comment: reuns is it $x^{p^n-1}-1$

Comment: How many roots does this polynomial have